# Let $S$ be the set of all the numbers of the form $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{3^k}$ where $a_k=0\text{, }2$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be the set of all the numbers of the form $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{3^k}$ where $a_k=0\text{, }2$.

I want to answer the following question about $S$?

1. Is $S$ uncountable?
2. Is $S$ closed?

Attempt:

If I consider the ternary representation of reals, then $S=[0,2]-$ {all those expression where $a_k=1$}

When $a_k=1$ then we have $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}3^{-k}$$ which is a basic geometric series with common ratio $1/3$ and initial term 1. So it adds up to $3/2$

Then $S=[0,2]-\{3/2\}$ so it is uncountable.

Am I going the right way?

Comment: Hint:  argue that it is in bijection with the usual binary representations of numbers on $[0,1]$

Comment: @lulu Suppose I take the expression where a_k=2 for all $k$ then we have $\sum 23^{-k}$ and this sums to $4/3$ which is not in $[0,1]$ ??

Comment: So, change the bijection.  Your string is just a string of $0's$ and $2's$ and such strings are clearly in bijection with strings of $0's$ and $1's$.

Comment: @lulu I have understood what you are trying to say. Thanks for that. Can you please check my approach and whatever I have written in the OP. I will be thankful.

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote.  Amongst the ternary numbers, the complement of those for which no $a_i=1$ is not just the single element for which all the $a_i=1$.

Comment: Check ternary representation of Cantor set. http://www.math.ou.edu/~kkornelson/teaching/m5453/ternary_expansion.pdf